# initialI18nStore is empty when i18next-http-backend is used

Tags: i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next, i18next-http-backend

I am using `next-i18next` with `i18next-chained-backend` for `i18next-fs-backend` & `i18next-http-backend` in a Next.js app, where `i18next-fs-backend` is used as [server-side cache](https://www.i18next.com/how-to/caching#server-side-next.js-caching-with-filesystem).

It seems like there is an issue with the updation of cache, from my understanding when the `expirationTime` exceeds `i18next-http-backend` fetches the latest locales from the API and `i18next-fs-backend` removes the locales present in `loadPath` and adds the fetched locales in `addPath` essentially replacing the locales present in the filesystem with the latest one.

The plugin is able to remove the locales from `loadPath` but after fetching the latest locales from API, it does not add it to `addPath`.

I am also using the custom request option as seen here in my `next-i18next.config.js`:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const ChainedBackend = require('i18next-chained-backend');

/**
 * @type {import('next-i18next').UserConfig}
 */
module.exports = {
  // debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  // reloadOnPrerender: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  debug: true,
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'es', 'zh'],
  },
  lng: 'en',
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  preload: ['en', 'es', 'zh'],
  ns: ['common'],
  defaultNS: 'common',
  backend: {
    backends:
      typeof window === 'undefined'
        ? [
            require('i18next-fs-backend/cjs'),
            require('i18next-http-backend/cjs'),
          ]
        : [],
    backendOptions:
      typeof window === 'undefined'
        ? [
            {
              loadPath: './public/locales_cache/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
              addPath: './public/locales_cache/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
              // expirationTime: 60 * 1000 * 60, // 1 hour
              expirationTime: 60 * 1000 * 2, // 2 min
            },
            {
              loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
              request: async (_options, url, _payload, callback) => {
                try {
                  const [locale] = url.split('/');
                  const result = await axios(
                    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/contents/webapp_content/`
                  );
                  const content = result.data[locale] || {};

                  callback(null, { status: 200, data: content });
                } catch (error) {
                  callback(error, null);
                }
              },
            },
          ]
        : [],
  },
  use: typeof window === 'undefined' ? [ChainedBackend] : [],
  react: {
    useSuspense: false,
  },
  returnNull: false,
  serializeConfig: false,
};
```

The config is also passed to pages that use SSR and SSG like so:

```js
// src/pages/index.tsx

import React from 'react';

import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';

import { Landing } from '@/containers/Landing/Landing';
import { Layout } from '@/layout/Layout';

import nextI18nConfig from '../../next-i18next.config.js';

export default function LandingPage() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Landing />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({
  locale = 'en',
}) => {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common'], nextI18nConfig)),
    },
  };
};
```

### Environment

- *runtime version*: node v18.16.0
- *os*: Linux
- *i18next*: ^22.5.1
- *i18next-chained-backend*: ^4.3.0
- *i18next-fs-backend*: ^2.1.3
- *i18next-http-backend*: ^2.2.1
- *react-i18next*: ^12.3.1

It should update the cache after fetching the latest locales